# How Can I disconnect a BT device in Java using bluecove?

Tags: java, bluetooth, bluecove

I'm new to bluetooth communication using Java. Looking at the bluecove documentation I did the following to be able to communicate with a bluetooth device:

1. Discover It
2. Get the `StreamConnection` via Connector.open`
3. Use the `InputStream` and the `OutputStream` to communicate

The only thing that i didn't find in the documentation is how to close the communication.

The code I implemented, guessing the disconnection strategy, is the following:

```java
    public void Connect() throws IOException
    {
        final int service = 5;        
        String conString = "btspp://"+Dev.getBluetoothAddress()+":"+service;

        Connection = (StreamConnection) Connector.open(conString);        
        inStream = Connection.openInputStream();
        outStream = Connection.openOutputStream();
    }

    public void Disconnect() throws IOException
    {        
        Connection.close();
    }
```

`Dev` is the `RemoteDevice` I got from Discovery.

When the call to the Connect function comes after the Disconnect I always get the following exception:

```
javax.bluetooth.BluetoothConnectionException: Failed to connect; [10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
```

Can someone tell me how to close the connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.
The call to  `Connection.close()` have to be done after the close of the streams obtained from the call to the function `Connection.openInputStream()` and `Connection.openOutputStream()`

The disconnect function now is the following:

```
    public void Disconnect() throws IOException
    {        
        inStream.close();
        outStream.close();
        Connection.close();
        inStream = null;
        outStream = null;
        Connection = null;
    }
```